# React app - npm module - error within file within static folder

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, minify

I am working on a react app which uses a certain npm module. When I run the app, an error is being produced. If I look in the sources tab in the dev tools and hover over the `index.js` file where the error is happening, I get a path like this:

Error:

`http://localhost:3000/static/js/C:/packages/stt-adapters/speechmatics/index.js`

What is this static folder inside localhost, is this something I can access, or is this being generated by the minified code in the npm module?

I'm very stuck, as I can't find this file where the error is happening and do logs and make edits.

I would be very grateful for any clues.

Comment: Have you did npm i ?

Comment: Hello Shilpe, I believe so. But I will try again, if you think it will fix it?

Comment: Yes, it will fix most probably and not then check your node version, there might be a compatibility issue that can also be there.